# Change default encoding in Thunderbird compose email using Config Editor

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

It defaults to Western-1252, I prefer ASCII. Any way to get it to use that using `user.js`/`about:config`?

Comment: How are those two different if you only input ASCII characters anyway?

Comment: _If_ I only input ASCII characters (which is not always the case), they aren't any different.